# Is there a way to classify simple non-spectral images in ArcGIS?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.4, classification, geotiff-tiff

I was wondering whether there's a way to classify simple non-spectral TIFF images in ArcGIS (maybe based on similar colour values of image pixels like graphic software applications such as Photoshop can do)?

Comment: Please decide which of ArcGIS and ERDAS you wish to ask about in this question. Otherwise you are effectively asking two questions which goes against the [Tour].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the image is in RGB color, you can use [image classification tool](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/latest/extensions/spatial-analyst/image-classification/image-classification-using-spatial-analyst.htm) to extract some data using maximum-likelihood classification for example. You need to take training site for the area of interest. I use it sometime to extract some information from maps instead of digitizing. But you have to make sure that area you want to extract is clear enough.

You need Spatial Analyst to use image classification tool.

Comment: Thanks, very helpful answer. What do you mean by 'clear enough'?

Comment: Sometimes when the area you want to classify has various colors crossing each other like in topographic maps, it may be difficult to extract the information easily and clearly, so you need some processing in graphic software like photoshop or gimp before start classification. But it depends on the image, so you can judge by yourself.

Comment: Great, thanks!
Is the image classification tool the only available option?

Comment: As far as I know this the only tool to do image classification in ArcGIS